# What steps and properties are involved in this Summation simplification?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have reference material that shows how to get from step 2 to 3 by recognizing the harmonic series. But how do they get from step 1 to 2?

[image: balls and bins probability]

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when $i$ runs from $1$ to $b$, $b-i+1$ runs from $b$ to $1$, descending and one by one. So you can just change the order of the sum to go from $1$ to $b$ ascending and one by one.